# jQuery Fullscreen Background Plugin Modification

Tags: jquery, plugins, background, fullscreen

I discovered a great but simple jQuery fullscreen background plugin:

http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/jquery-plugin-fullscreen-background/

I need to one modification: be able to change the backgrounds. Not sure how to implement. There would be bullets which correspond to each background image in the collection. If user clicks on any bullet, the existing background image is replaced with the corresponding image. A slideshow of sorts. Any help appreciated. Not sure if can be done using jQuery in the page alone, or if necessary to modify plugin JS file (edit existing functions or add a function).

Comment: show what have you tried ?

Comment: Developed locally at the moment. Here is a function I tried (target for bullet onclicks):  
  
function changeBackground(image) {  
$("#background-image").attr('src', '/images/backgrounds/' + image);  
$("#background-image").fullscreenBackground();  
}  
  
Doesn't work as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://blog.aaronvanderzwan.com/2012/07/maximage-2-0/. It uses [jquery cycle  slideshow plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) and allows you to make any slideshow a fullscreen background slideshow. Because it is based on Cycle it gives you all of the options to use bullets, pagers, etc.